# Add new API-Versions to publisher via REST

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using APIM 1.10 to add new APIs via the REST-API (see: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/apidocs/publisher/#!/operations#APIsApi#apisPost)

If I add my first version of an api it works fine. The new API is listed in Publisher.
But if I use the same add-methode with the same data (except the version- and the endpoint-element). I receive the message: "Resource Already Exists"

Question: Which is the best way to add a new version of a existing API via REST?

Should I use update-methode instead, but it is not an update?!?!

Please help me!

Thx, in advance

Marty

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Which is the best way to add a new version of a existing API
>   via REST?

You have to use [Copy API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/apidocs/publisher/#!/operations#APIsApi#apisCopyApiPost) and provide new version as query parameter like below.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer b0982cd2aacd463ff5f63cd5ebe58f4a" -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:9763/api/am/publisher/v0.9/apis/copy-api?apiId=890a4f4d-09eb-4877-a323-57f6ce2ed79b&newVersion=2.0.0"
```

Comment: *So* from my point of view the process to add a new api-version looks like this:<br/>

1. Check if api already exists: 
    via "Get ALL APIs" -> loop to the list (in my case 400 apis) to identify the affected API-Id

2. If exists call "Copy API" (with api-id) -> set new version

3. Call "Update API" -> set new endpoint and other optional parameter like description


Is my assuption correct?

Regards

Marty

Comment: If you know the apiId or combination of `provider-name-version`, you don't need to iterate through 400 APIs.

Comment: Thxs for the tip with the provider-name-version combination, but unfortunately we have a lot of apinames with a minus in the api-name. So that didn't work. Now I am use the first approach: Read all existings APIs to extract the api-id.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution looks like this:

- read all existing apis
- cluster the apis via name, context, versions in a hashmap
- before adding a new api i check if a other version of this api exists
- if yes, i use the copy rest-methode with addition update-methode
- if no, i can use the add-methode

Regards
Marty